# ASP.Net 3.5 password recovery SMTP settings

Tags: asp.net, passwords

Within ASP.Net - I'm using the built in password recovery wizard.

Is there any way of adding SMTP authentication to the Mail Authentication wizard - without having to add it to the web.config?  Or can it be injected somewhere in the code-behind?

My aspx code is below - there is currently no code-behind:

```
       <asp:PasswordRecovery ID="PasswordRecovery1" runat="server" borderStyle="None" 
        borderWidth="1px"  Font-Size="10pt" Font-Names="Verdana" onsendingmail="PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail">
    <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />
    <MailDefinition From="info@mydomain.co.uk" Priority="High" 
        Subject="My Domain - new, temporary password" BodyFileName="forgotpassword.txt">
    </MailDefinition>
    <UserNameTemplate>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" 
            style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0">

                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:Small;">
                                Enter your User Name to receive your password.</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:Small;">
                                <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                    ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="PasswordRecovery1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" CommandName="Submit" Text="Submit" 
                                    ValidationGroup="PasswordRecovery1" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </UserNameTemplate>
</asp:PasswordRecovery>
```

Currently I just get the message:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException
>   Mailbox unavailable. 
>   The server response was: must be authenticated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that your SMTP server requires your application to authenticate itself before it can send emails through it.

You're probably using `SmtpClient` under-the-hood. The defaults for the .NET SMTP client are defined in your application's configuration file, in this case your web.config. The only other place is if you manually manage the `SmtpClient` because you handle the PasswordRecovery control's events.

`PasswordRecovery` exposes no property that gives control over the underlying SMTP client.

Note that I strongly advise against using `WebControls` because using them means you surrender a lot of control over your application: both logic and presentational. I'll also note that the markup you provided is not valid as it uses presentational attributes, and using `<table>` for layout is strongly discouraged.

Comment: Thank you - just confirmed what I though.  Cheers, Mark

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            try
            {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\database\personal.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=60;User Instance=True"))
            {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserName,Password FROM Logintable Where emailid= '" + txtEmail.Text.Trim() + "'", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            }
            if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
            {



                            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage Msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                            // Sender e-mail address.
                            Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text);
                            // Recipient e-mail address.
                            Msg.To.Add(txtEmail.Text);
                            Msg.Subject = "Your Password Details";
                            Msg.Body = "Hi, <br/>Please check your Login Detailss<br/><br/>Your Username: " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserName"] + "<br/><br/>Your Password: " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Password"] + "<br/><br/>";
                            Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                            // your remote SMTP server IP.
                            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                            smtp.Port = 587;
                            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("youremail@gmail.com", "N@@@@@@@@");
                            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                            smtp.Send(Msg);

                            //Msg = null;
                            Label3.Text = "Your Password Details Sent to your mail";
                            // Clear the textbox valuess
                            txtEmail.Text = "";
                    }
                        else
                        {
                              lbltxt.Text = "The Email you entered not exists.";
                        }
                        }
                     catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Label2.Text = "Error Occured: " + ex.Message.ToString();

                    }
            }
       }
```